# Findbugs false positive: Dereference of the result of readLine() without nullcheck

Tags: java, findbugs, false-positive

The following seems to be a false positive of Findbugs.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String s = br.readLine();
 if(s == null) {
      return;
 }
```

at the line of the `if`, I'm getting the message

> Dereference of the result of readLine() without nullcheck

Can someone confirm this being a false positive? How to prevent it (read: how to write functionally equivalent code on which Findbugs does not complain)?

- Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- FindBugs Feature 3.0.1.20150306-5afe4d1

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
try {
  s = br.readLine();
  if(s == null) {return ;}
}
catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Try using try catch block

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion .